Construct a sparse tensor while propagating gradient?
I have code similar to this I would like to make faster:
# indices: indices of a 3d tensor
# values associated to the indices


result = torch.zeros((L, N, N))
for idx, (i,j,k) in enumerate(indices):
        mask = torch.zeros_like(result)
        mask[i][j][k] = 1.0
        img = img + mask * values[idx]

Now, even if I chose to make a sparse mask, I notice that each iteration runs slower. Is there a simple solution to a function that will propagate the gradient of the form img = func(indices, values) 
I'm looking for a solution that takes advantage of vectorization or/and sparse data structures

Can you clarify what you are trying to do? What is the purpose of creating mask = torch.zeros_like(result) as a full 3D tensor just to assign 1.0 to a single i,j,k index? If you want to compute img = img + mask * values[idx] where mask only has a single non-zero value, why not just compute img[i,j,k] = img[i,j,k] + values[idx]?

The solution is as simple as constructing a new sparse coo tensor.
value_tensor = torch.sparse_coo_tensor(indices=indices, values=values, size=(L, N, N))

